# Uncomputability of Certain Functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

A standard proof in an introductory discrete math course to prove that not all functions are computable is as follows:

$(1)$ Show that the set of all computer programs is countable

$(2)$ Show that the set of all functions on the reals is uncountable

It hence follows from $(1)$ and $(2)$ that no surjection exists from the set of computer programs to the set of functions. Thus there is always some function $f$ that has no pre-image, and is hence not computable.

However, the above proof doesn’t account for the fact that there may be multiple mappings. What’s to say that there doesn’t exist some mapping that maps some program to $f$, leaving out another function $g$?

Comment: What is a multiple mapping?

Comment: Just multiple ways to map one set to the other. For instance, $(0,1)$ can be mapped to $(0,2)$ in two ways, by the function $x$ and by the function $2x$

Comment: This is just a proof by contradiction: if you could find a program for every function than it would provide a surjective map from a countable map to an uncountable one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, for every function $f$ on the reals, there is a map from the set of computable functions to the set of functions on the reals that hits $f$.

One might view the choice of map from {programs} to {functions on the reals} as a choice of semantics of the programming language. The statement you have proved is that there is no semantics which allows you to express every function (though for any given function, there is a semantics which can express that function; much stronger, for any given $f$ there is a semantics for which $f$ *is the result of evaluating the program whose text is `foo`*, although it's liable to be a rather silly semantics in any such case, and you will struggle to specify it concretely!).

Comment: So when we say that there are functions no program in any language can compute, do we assume that all these programs are based on mathematical algorithms, and that the number of possible mappings is hence fundamentally limited?

Comment: The number of mappings is not limited. The number of mappings *which you can specify* is limited, because you can only specify countably many things, because you use finite strings from a finite alphabet to do the specification.

Comment: I know; but if the number of mappings isn’t limited, why are there examples of uncomputable functions at all? What does it mean for a function to be uncomputable, if with some mapping, it does have a pre-image?

Comment: Because uncomputability is defined *relative to a particular encoding scheme* (in this case, the formalism of Turing machines). A function is "uncomputable" if no Turing machine computes it. There are only countably many Turing machines, so Turing machines can only express countably many of the various possible semantics of a programming language.

Comment: Everything is clear now. Thanks so much for your help!